# Confluent connect 5.5.1 is throwing Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread |

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am having a large cluster of Confluent Kafka comprising of multiple sub-clusters
One for Zookeeper, another for Kafka broker with Schema Registry and KSQL streams
And one cluster for Connect.

My connect cluster is having issues since I have configured the rest.advertised.host.name for all of my worker instances to FQDN as per the article [here](https://rmoff.net/2019/11/22/common-mistakes-made-when-configuring-multiple-kafka-connect-workers/) -

Following are the errors I am continously seeing in the connect distributed log files on all nodes -

> connectDistributed.out

Error 1-

```
[2021-08-12 14:07:48,932] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-XYZ-0, groupId=connect-XYZ] Attempt to
heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:1054)
```

Error 2-

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | connect-XYZ"
```

> Following are the connect worker properties -

```
bootstrap.servers=production-kafka-elb.int.supportabc.platform.co.uk:9092
group.id=connect-cluster-cc
connect.protocol=compatible
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets-cc
offset.storage.replication.factor=5
config.storage.topic=connect-configs-cc
config.storage.replication.factor=5
status.storage.topic=connect-status-cc
status.storage.replication.factor=5
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
rest.port=8085
rest.advertised.host.name=bblpkaa011.int.supportabc.platform.co.uk
rest.advertised.port=8085
plugin.path=/usr/share/java,/apps/confluent-5.5.1/share/java/
key.converter.schema.registry.url=abc-production-kafka-elb.int.supportabc.platform.co.uk:8081
value.converter.schema.registry.url=abc-production-kafka-elb.int.supportabc.platform.co.uk:8081
```

I am sure each worker has 6GB assigned to it -

> See the process trace -

```
java -Xmx6G -Xms6G -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dkafka.logs.dir=/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../logs -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties -cp /apps/confluent-5.5.1/share/java/confluent-security/connect/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/share/java/kafka/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/share/java/confluent-common/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../ce-broker-plugins/build/libs/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../ce-broker-plugins/build/dependant-libs/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../ce-auth-providers/build/libs/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../ce-auth-providers/build/dependant-libs/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../ce-rest-server/build/libs/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../ce-rest-server/build/dependant-libs/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../ce-audit/build/libs/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../ce-audit/build/dependant-libs/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../share/java/kafka/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../share/java/confluent-metadata-service/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../share/java/rest-utils/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../share/java/confluent-common/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../share/java/confluent-security/schema-validator/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../support-metrics-client/build/dependant-libs-2.12.10/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../support-metrics-client/build/libs/*:/usr/share/java/support-metrics-client/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../support-metrics-fullcollector/build/dependant-libs-2.12.10/*:/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/../support-metrics-fullcollector/build/libs/*:/usr/share/java/support-metrics-fullcollector/* -javaagent:/apps/ad/java-agent-20.9.0.30985-latest/javaagent.jar org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed /apps/confluent-5.5.1/etc/kafka/connect-distributed-worker-cc.properties
```

Please help how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer to get rid of Out of Memory errors is to increase the Xms and Xmx memory allocation variables in the process config and restart it gracefully.

> Check if the existing process has a variable like shown below

```
./connect-distributed:  export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xms6G -Xmx6G"
```

> Check the output of free -m or top on the target server

```
KiB Mem : 32304516 total,   288648 free, 17298612 used,
```

> Change the memory allocation limits as per the available memory in the
> system

```
./connect-distributed:export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx28G -Xms24G"
```

> Gracefully stop the process on the console using flag below. If
> -SIGTERM doesn't work use -SIGKILL

```
kill -SIGTERM <PID>
```

> Restart the service using the usual restart command

```
/apps/confluent-5.5.1/bin/connect-distributed -daemon /apps/confluent-5.5.1/etc/kafka/connect-distributed-worker1.properties
```

> After this restart everything should stabilize

Answer (score 1):

> What actually happened!

On the Connect cluster this appears when all nodes on the cluster have entered into what Confluent calls a 'STOP-THE-WORLD' event of heavy re-balancing.

Which essentially means no matter how many connector workers / tasks were running on the cluster before, they all stop processing whatever they were before and jump into re-balancing mode fighting for a leader.

> Why it happened!

One of your Connect worker properties file is set to this -> `connect.protocol=compatible`

OR

Some other major change in the connect worker properties or worker restart without pausing the running tasks first

> Solution

```
rest.advertised.host.name=<FULLY QUALIFIED HOST NAME> OR <IP.ADDRESS>
rest.advertised.port=8083
```

I have been able to solve this by following below steps in the order mentioned below -

1. Stopped the Connect worker running with `connect.protocol=compatible`
2. Stopped other Connect workers
3. Added two properties in all the worker properties file
   -rest.advertised.host.name=
   -rest.advertised.port=
4. Restarted the Connect workers one by one and noticed the below property being picked up

> ```
> [kafka@abchostnamekk01 logs]$ grep -ri 'info advertised' connectDistributed.out
>     [2021-08-12 14:06:50,809] INFO Advertised URI: http://abchostnamekk01.domain.com:8083
> ```